# Checking for latest installers of famous freeware/opensource software

Tags: windows, internet, setup, releases

I always store in my HDD setup files of software which I generally install after windows installation (like google chrome, skype ... etc). Updating these setup files manually.

I wonder if there is any free application, which checks for updated software and automatically downloads setup files to predefined folder?

Comment: More suitable at http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try http://ninite.com/

It works for most popular freeware. Auto download install and update. Just one click

Answer (score 0):

I vaguely recall that *win-get* does this.  I don't remember if I've ever used it or not.

Note that Ubuntu Linux automatically downloads updates for most third-party software by default.  It pops up a message asking if you want to install the updates.  If you tell it to install them all, it installs them all without asking you any more questions.

Answer (score 0):

Checks versions of **all** installed SW **without downloading**:

- SUMo
- Software Informer